Disclosure announcement: I've joined BitGo
I'm happy to announce that I've joined BitGo, Inc. as a software engineer. I don't think that this will influence my contributions here, but if the case should ever arise that a moderation task would present a conflict of interest I'll ask my moderator colleagues to take care of it.
Cheers,
Murch

Congratulations!

Congratulations indeed, BitGo is awesome!
